# let $D_n$ be the number of permutations of $\{1,2,3,.....n\}$ which leave no element fixed.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $n\geq2$ and let $D_n$ be the number of permutations of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ which leave no element  fixed. How to write an expression for $D_n$ in terms of $D_k$? I don't know how to start. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure, but as per my calculations, I think the following holds as well:

$ 1 + [n(n-1)/2! ]D_2 + [n(n-1)(n-2)/3!]D_3 + ... + [n!/n!]D_n = n!$

The explaination for LHS:
The first term : number of permutations with $n$ fixed element.  
The second term : number of permutations with  $n-2$ fixed elements.  
The third term : number of permutations with $n-3$ fixed elements.  
...  
The last term : number of permutations with $0$ fixed elements.

Comment: Why don't you consider the number of permutation with $(n-1)$ fixed elements?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to express $D_n$ in terms of earlier $D_k$. We describe one of them.

Suppose that a permutation $\pi$ leaves no element of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ fixed. Then $\pi$ takes $n$ to some element $j\lt n$. There are $n-1$ choices for $j$.

Take a fixed choice $j$. Maybe $\pi$ sends $j$ to $n$. Then there are by definition $D_{n-2}$ permutations of our set minus $n$ and $j$ that leave no element fixed.

Or maybe $\pi$ takes $j$ to some object other than $n$. In that case, make a new permutation $\pi'$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ by removing $n$ and letting $\pi$ stay unchanged, except that whoever is mapped by $\pi$ to $n$ is now mapped to $j$. Every permutation of $\{1,2,\,\dots,n-1\}$ that leaves no element fixed is obtained in this way. Thus there are $D_{n-1}$ permutations of this type.

It follows that $D_n=(n-1)(D_{n-2}+D_{n-1})$.

Comment: Sorry to say but my book gives the answer to the above problem as $D_n = n! − 1 \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}C_k D_{n-k}$

Comment: How to arrive at that

Comment: The one I wrote is correct, as is the Inclusion/Exclusion formula of your comment. Kaj Hansen in an unfortunately deleted answer was giving hints toward that. You will find an explanation of the recurrence you mention (as well as the more computationally useful recurrence in my answer) in the Wikipedia article on derangements.

Comment: I notice Srinivas K has sketched a proof of the identity your book mentions.